# API e-imzo в visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

Может у кого-то был опыт использования e-imzo, электронная цифровая подпись для Узбекистана. После установки ПО можно зайти по пути https://127.0.0.1:64443/  и есть ссылка на их API документацию. Но я не могу понять, где взять эти плагины, как работать с API? Понять не могу как обратиться к этим командам через api

```
НАПРИМЕР: pkcs7 - Плагин для работы с форматом PKCS#7/CMS
append_pkcs7_attached - Добавить подпись в существующий документ PKCS#7/CMS
CAPIWS.callFunction({
    plugin    :"pkcs7",
    name      :"append_pkcs7_attached",
    arguments :[
      //Ранее созданный документ PKCS#7/CMS в кодировке BASE64
      pkcs7_64,
      //Идентификатор ключа подписывающего лица (полученный из фукнции других плагинов)
      id
    ]
  },
  function(event, data){
    console.log(data);
  },
  function(error){
    window.alert(error);
  }
);
```

Comment: я не понимаю, что такое CAPIWS?? вроде как  процесс windows, но как к нему цепляться?